# Rails: ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique how to find for which column the exception was raised

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently there is a unique index on my column with name "index_unique_devices_on_dsn" . when i am saving duplicating record i am getting mysql exception and i am handling that exception using class `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` . if in the future if i am adding multiple columns and each column having its own unique index then how can i programmatically identify for which column this uniqueness exception was raised. ? i don't want to use .valid? method of rails as it is going to run validation again.

Comment: What do you mean you are "handling that exception"? Can you post some code so that we may better assist? What is the actual exception that you are rescuing because usually the exception message will provide details. In addition you should probably be validating the uniqueness in the model anyway at which point to would not have to rescue and could just use `model_instance.errors` to see the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you'd use the non-exception versions like [`save`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save) or [create](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create) instead of `save!` and `create!`. Then check which columns are invalid on the [model's validation errors](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html).

```
user = User.create(name: "Duplicate")
if user.model.errors.include?(:name)
  ...
end
```

However, the ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique exception comes from the database. There's no validation error.

You can fix this by adding your own uniqueness validation to the model which runs before Rails tries to save the model.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
end
```

Now you'll get a validation error.

However, this requires a query to check uniqueness. That can affect performance, and also lead to race conditions. Imagine you try to create two Users with the same name at the same time. They both check if the name is taken, they both see that it is not, and they both try to insert. One succeeds, one fails with an ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique.

Instead, use the excellent [database_validations](https://github.com/toptal/database_validations) gem which turns database errors into validation errors. This is safer, faster, and you only need one way to check for validation errors.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, db_uniqueness: true
end
```

Comment: Did not know about the database_validations gem this is nice if you use the native rails supported RDBMSs